# Has anyone succeeded with static linking opencv for android?

Tags: android

I have to fix the problem of android static linking opencv libraries. We have an app using dynamic linking using opencv manager. 
I have already checked the official documentation on opencv.org and not found details of the steps to configure static linking for android.

Question: How do you link OpenCV libraries statically to an android project?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but there was no comment link - I have had some success with opencv and android - have a look at the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c)

```
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
```

Comment: Thanks,peterretief! I just configue the eclipse follow the step of opecv offical doc,and if I changed the code of examples like fd-detection "if(!OpenCVLoader.iniDebug())" my app camera couldn't open,if I didn't change the code it always says "Package not found",I know it mean static initialization failed! Could show me the steps to static the examples of opencv-2.4.3-android-sdk ?Thanks

Comment: could you add the link of the tutorial you are following?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android I follow the steps of this link

Comment: I get a build error using android 2.2 but if I use 3 as in the tutorial it works fine